# Gnus doesn't see mail, even though files are there

Tags: gnus, email

My [`message-directory`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/message/Various-Message-Variables.html#index-message_002ddirectory) is `~/.emacs.d/mail`, this is where [Gnus](http://gnus.org/) stores all my mail. Suppose I have a directory `misc` that contains some email in `nnml` format. I create a Group `mail.misc`, move directory `misc` under `~/.emacs.d/mail/misc`. But Gnus doesn't see my mail automatically, even though the files, corresponding to articles, exist.

How to make Gnus see my email under the corresponding Group? I think it has to do with `.overview` file.

Comment: Gnus expects to have full control over email in nnml-format, so you should expect problems when you move files around behinds Gnus' back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Gnus doesn't see some or all mail in your mail directory, even though the files are there, it may be for 2 reasons.

1. You miss or have corrupted an `.overview` file. An `.overview` file is called a [NOV database](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/%7Elarsi/notes/nov-faq.txt), Gnus uses this file to track your mail.

   Call `nnml-generate-nov-databases-directory`, enter directory containing your mail. Or, call `nnml-generate-nov-databases` to update all mail directories. See [Section “Mail Spool”](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Spool.html#Mail-Spool) of Gnus manual.
2. Some of your articles are hidden.

   First try <kbd>T S</kbd> ([`gnus-summary-show-all-threads`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Thread-Commands.html#index-gnus_002dsummary_002dshow_002dall_002dthreads)). If that doesn't work, show all [*dormant*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Unread-Articles.html#index-gnus_002ddormant_002dmark) articles with <kbd>/ D</kbd> ([`gnus-summary-limit-include-dormant`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Limiting.html#index-gnus_002dsummary_002dlimit_002dinclude_002ddormant)). Remove dormant status with <kbd>M c</kbd> ([`gnus-summary-clear-mark-forward`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Setting-Marks.html#index-gnus_002dsummary_002dclear_002dmark_002dforward)).